# Is there an inbuilt method in python(pandas) which can simulate a single day from multiple days

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a time series data for solar radiation with 15 min time step values (from 1st June till 30th June) for a month. My aim is to simulate one single day from all the 30 days by taking an average of each time instants. For example, initially i have 30 different values at 11am , 11.15am, 11.45am and so on. I want to average those 30 values so that i have a single value at 11am, 11.15am, 11.45am respectively.

Comment: Could you include your code here to make it easier for people who want to help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract minutes to separate column an group by it:

```
data['Minutes15'] = data['Date'].apply(lambda x: int(x.minute/15) *15))
data.groupby('Minutes15').mean()
```

Where *Date* is your date column in datetime format